# mysql_real_escape_string not working on linux server but its working for my localhost

Tags: php, mysql

```
$intro=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["intro"]);
$description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
```

If i post the any special character value it is not stored properly.

Comment: so you get any error ? try : error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');      on top of your script in the linux server.

Comment: Please check your PHP version on server is it same as your localhost as mysql_real_escape_string this function has be deprecated in newest version of PHP.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: @AlankarMore: My PHP Version is 5.3..

Comment: @Federico: i didn't get any error but the content shows not properly . if i stored BHARATH'S but its shows me BHARATH/'s like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try : on top of your script in the linux server (better before anything else)

  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
- look in the 'page source code' if a php error is present.

Maybe on the linux yoou need to specify the connection :

```
$intro = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["intro"], $my_mysql_connection);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"], $my_mysql_connection);
```

- follow **Jay Blanchard** suggestion.

Is possible that the php on the linux is running magic_quotes_gpc enabled...
Please look in

```
echo php_info();
```

if php version < 5.3 and magic_quotes_gpc enabled, try this on top of page:

```
function stripslashes_recurr($o)
{   $o = is_array($o) ? array_map('stripslashes_recurr', $o) : stripslashes($o);
    return $o;
}

$magic_quotes_gpc = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? true : false;  
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);                             
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase', 0);
if($magic_quotes_gpc) $_POST = stripslashes_recurr($_POST);
```

Comment: Not working .. the descriptions shows like..<div class=\"panel-heading\">IT</div>
<div class=\"panel-body\"><i class=\"fa fa-laptop fa-5x pull-left text-orange\"></i>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt ipsum vel turpis fermentum pulvinar. Suspendisse efficitur nulla nec bibendum vestibulum. Nam sit amet nisi interdum, aliquet urna ut, venenatis augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque vel rhoncus nulla, et elementum justo.</p>
</div>

Comment: try php_info() for version.

Comment: Thanks for your query it was working fine what i expected the result.